# Could not find the relationship between tables

Tags: laravel

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model{
        
            use HasFactory;
        
            protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'name', 'description', 'price'];
        
            public function  category(){
                     
                
                return $this->belongs('App\Models\Catogery');
            
            }
        }
```

**Catogery Model**

```
 class Catogery extends Model{
    use HasFactory;
    public function products()
        {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
        }
    }
```

**ProductController**

```
public function index()
{
   $products = Product::with('category')->get();
   return $products; 
}
```

I did write the  above code to extract the all the products in each category.But It gives the following error.

```
  Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\\Models\\Product].
```

Comment: laravel version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in the Product model:

```
return $this->belongs('App\Models\Catogery');
```

it needs to be:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Catogery');
```

and it will work.

Comment: It does not work, the reason the morph....

Comment: morph? you didn't specify that anywhere in question :) try with another one with more details.